# How to detect that the HTML element has text by clicking on text content area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `text content` and a `boxed` element in a `div` but still changes happen when I click on `boxed` element while I need to make changes only when I click on `text content`.

Here is the code:https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/u0g8LLLo/

```
<div>
some text
<span class="box"></span>
</div>

<div>
some text
</div>

<div><span class="box"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','div', function(){
    if (!$(this).text().trim().length > 0) {
        $(this).text("foo");
    } else {
    $(this).append('<span>You clicked on a text</span>');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you bind an event handler to a node, or use event delegation, `this` refers to the node the event was bonded to (or delegated to in the case of `on`).

Click the `.box` inside the 1st `div` element, gets the `div` as `this`. Since the `div` element contains text, you the wrong result.

Instead you should get the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). The target is the actual element clicked.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {

  var $target = $(e.target); // the event target
  
  if (!$target.text().trim().length > 0) {
    $target.text("foo");
  } else {
    $target.append('<span>You clicked on a text</span>');
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  some text
  <span class="box"></span>
</div>

<div>
  some text
</div>

<div><span class="box"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have id's and classes you can try comparing ids or classes

```
$(document).on('click','div', function(e){
if (e.target.id.toString() == "box" || $(e.target).hasClass("box")) {
    $(this).append('<span>foo</span>');
} else {
    $(this).append('<span>You clicked on a text</span>');
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/q6vbohxm/**

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you should do. As this selects the body element and any element inside body that has text, will go into the if statement, if you need elese statement as well, you add so after the if.

```
$(document).on('click','body', function(e){
   var clickedTag, text;
   clickedtag = e.target;
   text = $(clickedtag).text().trim();
   if(text.length > 0){
     console.log(text);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your text in separate element and fire click event on that element and also use .stopPropagation() method...

```
  $("#demo").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("your text element was clicked");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of event bubbling, so we need to stop that. Jquery having method to stop it `event.stopPropagation();`. Here I used `div *` selector to prevent firing event for all the child element inside `div`. Instead of `div` you can use any class to differentiate from other `div`

```js
$(document).on('click','div', function(){


    $(this).append('<span>You clicked on a text</span>');

    
}).on("click","div *", function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color:green;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
some text
<span class="box"></span>
</div>
```